# Core Data Import Failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks

I'm trying to import a large data set (~6,000) in to my core data application. I've read the Apple document "Efficiently Importing Data" and I think I set it up correctly. The weird thing is the application isn't crashing in the simulator, although it does if I run it with the Leaks instrument, but it isn't saving all the data. Sometimes it will only save 3-4 hundred other times it will save 3-4 thousand and rarely the whole data set. I think it's probably memory leak related and I'm pretty new to using NSAutoReleasePool, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    if (responseString) {
        NSArray *players = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

        NSUInteger LOOP_LIMIT = 100, count = 0;

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[AppController sharedAppController] managedObjectContext];
        [context setUndoManager:nil];

        for (int i=0; i<([players count] - 1); i++) {
            NSArray *info = [[players objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

            NSString *dateInfo = [info objectAtIndex:10];
            NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
            NSDateFormatter *fo = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [fo setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
            [fo setLocale:usLocale];
            [fo setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
            NSDate *dob = [fo dateFromString:dateInfo];

            Players *player = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Players"
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

            NSNumberFormatter *f = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

            player.playerID = [f numberFromString:[info objectAtIndex:0]];              
            player.lastName = [info objectAtIndex:1];
            player.firstName = [info objectAtIndex:2];
            player.position = [info objectAtIndex:4];

            NSString *teamName = [info objectAtIndex:3];

            NSFetchRequest *req = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

            NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teams" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [req setEntity:ent];
            [req setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

            NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"team=%@", teamName];
            [req setPredicate:pre];

            NSArray *list = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];

            if ([list count]) {
                Teams *team = [list objectAtIndex:0];

                player.team_Players_Teams = team;
            }

            count++;

            if (count == LOOP_LIMIT) {
                [context save:nil];

                [context reset];

                [pool drain];

                pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

                count = 0;
            }
        }

        if (count != 0) {
            NSLog(@"In Save Remaining");

            [context save:nil];

            [context reset];[pool drain];
        }
```

Comment: [pool drain] is missing at the end

Comment: True - I just added that but that shouldn't be affecting the actual import. There still has to be some error in the import process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything dodgy in the code either. Definitely no errors appearing in the log?

Btw one other optimisation tip covered in the Core Data pdf for importing data is to move the predicate creation outside the loop and use substitution variables.

Comment: Nope wasn't getting any errors. I finally got it to sort of work by upping the LOOP_LIMIT to 10000. It works every time now in simulator and on device, but not in instruments. Fortunately this is only done the initial start of the application so I don't think it should be an issue.

Comment: Edit above changed to 1,000 not 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious leaks but:

1. You could minimise the amount of memory used by `alloc init retain`-ing the `NSLocale`, `NSDateFormatter`, `NSNumberFormatter` and then `release`-ing them after the loop is complete.  These don't seem to change between runs of the loop.
2. I don't know Core Data but where does the `NSManagedObject`/`Player *player` object get released?  Is this autoreleased through Core Data?
3. As an aside, you can use `[list lastObject]` rather than `[list count]` and `[list objectAtIndex:0]` as the last two will crash if list is nil

Update based on response:

If nothing appears to make a difference then the next step is to simplify the code so as to remove any error sources.

1. Carry out my suggestions in #1 above to minimise the amount of code in the loop.
2. Check you're releasing the `list` object somewhere or that it is allocated as autorelease.
3. Remove the intermediate saving (all that code inside `count == LOOP_LIMIT`) and only save and drain the pool once all the arrays have been processed. You also should not need the code following on inside the `if (count != 0)`
4. Replace the `error:nil` statements with proper `error:&&error` and log errors.  To log the errors do the following (apologies but the code formatting doesn't seem to work - no idea why):
   `NSError *error = nil; //Declared upfront`

   `// Your streamlined code`

   `// ....`

   `error = nil; //Just before a fetchRequest or context:save`

   `/* After looping through all your code now attempt to save */`

   `if(![context save:&error]) {`

   ```
   NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   NSArray *detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
   if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
       for(NSError *detailedError in detailedErrors) {
           NSLog(@"DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
       }
   } else {
       NSLog(@" %@", [error userInfo]);
   }
   ```

   `}`
5. Then check the log to see if you're getting any odd messages. You can also use similar code anywhere in Core Data that you need to check for errors (i.e. `executeFetchRequest`). It's worth a shot to find out what the error is here.

Comment: The NSManagedObject Player should be released with the pool I believe. Unfortunately it's still crashing and I have no idea why.

Comment: Updated my original response with more options and comments.  I've removed my previous comments as they were too small to read the code